# Construct a result set from combinaiton of subdocuments with specific criteria with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the a collection called Brokers that holds the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5411c48fdf4ee218f4fed596"),
    "BrokerName" : "Broker 1",
    "SymbolsList" : [ 
        {
            "BaseCurrency" : "AUD",
            "QuoteCurrency" : "CAD",
            "Ask" : 1.00475,
            "Bid" : 1.0043,
        }, 
        {
            "BaseCurrency" : "AUD",
            "QuoteCurrency" : "CHF",
            "Ask" : 0.85119,
            "Bid" : 0.85084,
        }...
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5411c48fdf4ee218f4fed597"),
    "BrokerName" : "Broker 2",
    "SymbolsList" : [ 
        {
            "BaseCurrency" : "AUD",
            "QuoteCurrency" : "CAD",
            "Ask" : 1.00475,
            "Bid" : 1.0043,
        }, 
        {
            "BaseCurrency" : "CAD",
            "QuoteCurrency" : "CHF",
            "Ask" : 1.29119,
            "Bid" : 1.29084,
        }...
    ]
}
```

I need to extract from the collection a result sets that looks like this:

```
{
    Symbol1: {
        "BrokerName" : "Broker 1",
        "BaseCurrency" : "AUD",
        "QuoteCurrency" : "CAD",
        "Ask" : 1.00475,
        "Bid" : 1.0043
    },
    Symbol2: {
        "BrokerName" : "Broker 1",
        "BaseCurrency" : "AUD",
        "QuoteCurrency" : "CHF",
        "Ask" : 1.00475,
        "Bid" : 1.0043
    },
    Symbol3: {
        "BrokerName" : "Broker 2",
        "BaseCurrency" : "CAD",
        "QuoteCurrency" : "CHF",
        "Ask" : 1.00475,
        "Bid" : 1.0043
    }
},
{
    Symbol1: {
        "BrokerName" : "Broker 1",
        "BaseCurrency" : "EUR",
        "QuoteCurrency" : "USD",
        "Ask" : 1.00475,
        "Bid" : 1.0043
    },
    Symbol2: {
        "BrokerName" : "Broker 1",
        "BaseCurrency" : "EUR",
        "QuoteCurrency" : "CAD",
        "Ask" : 1.00475,
        "Bid" : 1.0043
    },
    Symbol3: {
        "BrokerName" : "Broker 1",
        "BaseCurrency" : "USD",
        "QuoteCurrency" : "CAD",
        "Ask" : 1.00475,
        "Bid" : 1.0043
    }
}
```

Those sets are constructed from 3 sub-documents in a way that the first and second "Symbols" has the same BaseCurrency (in example "AUD") 
and the 3rd "Symbol" BaseCurrency and QuoteCurrency are the remaining 2 QuoteCurrency of the first 2 Symbol ("CAD" and "CHF").

The "Symbol" should also include the "BrokerName" field so I can know what document it came from.

The combinations can come from the same collection (internal - BrokerName will be the same on all 3 Symbols) 
or across collections (BrokerName could be any of the existing documents in the DB).

Before I have transferred the data to MongoDB, I used C# classes to hold the data, and queried it using the following LINQ statement:

```
from Broker1 in BrokerList.AsParallel()
from Broker2 in BrokerList.AsParallel()
from Broker3 in BrokerList.AsParallel()
from Symbol1 in Broker1.SymbolsList.AsParallel()
from Symbol2 in Broker2.SymbolsList.AsParallel()
from Symbol3 in Broker3.SymbolsList.AsParallel()
where Symbol1.TradeAllowed == 1 && Symbol2.TradeAllowed == 1 && Symbol3.TradeAllowed == 1 &&
Symbol1.BaseCurrency == Symbol2.BaseCurrency && Symbol1.QuoteCurrency != Symbol2.QuoteCurrency &&
((Symbol1.QuoteCurrency + Symbol2.QuoteCurrency == Symbol3.BaseSymbolName) || (Symbol2.QuoteCurrency + Symbol1.QuoteCurrency == Symbol3.BaseSymbolName))
select new { Symbol1, Symbol2, Symbol3 }
```

I'm trying to find the equivalent query to get the data out of the MongoDB structure (because it was taking around 40 minutes to get the results of the query with classes and LINQ)...

P.S - BaseSymbolName is basicly a property that returns the Base and Quote currency concatenated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to clearly explain the logic behind "why" these items would be grouped together as they are in your example results. Also, asking for something with arbitrary "key" names (e.g  "Symbol1", "Symbol2", etc ) that are not present anywhere in your data is not going to result in a clean solution. Do you actually possibly mean just a "list" of that data per each document? Needs some further work to explain as there is no clear "grouping" pattern here

Comment: What I want to create is a list of all the permutation of the available data the meet the criteria. in a way that, I have documents that holds "brokers" data, and all the available symbols of those brokers, and I try to get all the combinations (in the symbols list, and between symbols list of different brokers) that meets the criteria. Symbol 1/2/3 are 3 sub-documents of the original data structure that I want to extract and name Symbol1/2/3. hope it clarify it better.

Comment: If you want all possible pairs (brokers, symbols) for some fixed list of symbols (like "all symbols appearing in all documents"), filtered on some criteria, then the aggregation framework won't be able to compute the kind of results you want from broker documents unless every broker document has all symbols represented in it.